# how i can save output in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have question about how I can save the result of function

I have function returns two output , and this function in for loop
so the value of output is changes .how I can save this output in folder.

Comment: Get the output in each iteration, and append it each time to another matrix. When the loop is done, save the matrix you were appending to with the `save` command - give it the -ascii option if you want to save it as ASCII data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i=1:N
   [out1 out2] = myfun();
   name = ['mySaveNumber_' num2str(i)];
   save(name);
end
```

Comment: Thank u Sevenless ....But when i try ur code it does not work ..I get error at name=[]

Comment: Thank u . I just change the folder name

Answer (score 0):

SELECT -> copy -> paste your output in a text file (it means i dont get your question)

Comment: I do not want to use copy and paste I want to use save in matlab to save the function output at every iteration